# Image responsiveness breaks when employing overflow-wrap property in its caption

Tags: html, css

In a web app I'm developing, users can upload photos (with captions) and share with one another.

I display each photo like a polaroid, using CSS to create the effect. For instance:

[image]

The design is responsive to varied screen-sizes (it's a requirement):

[image]

Here's the CSS code:

```
.canvas{
    background-color:white;
    padding:10px 10px 30px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:6px;
}

.image{
max-width:400px;
width:100%;
border-radius:12px;
}

.caption-canvas{
max-width:400px;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:-10px;
margin-top:1em;
}

.caption{
font-size:130%;
color:grey;
}

<div class="canvas">
    <img src="umb.png" class="image">
    <div class="caption-canvas">
        <span class="caption">This is an orange umbrella</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

So far so good.

But problems arise if the caption is a long string without breaks. E.g.:

[image]

However not to worry, one can add `overflow-wrap: break-word;` (to `.caption`) to take care of this:

[image]

But this gives birth to a new problem: **The polaroid canvas doesn't scale down with reduction in resolution any more, and overflows its container**. I.e.:

[image]

I can fix this responsiveness problem if I use `word-break: break-all;` instead. However I don't want to use that. It doesn't perform well for English text, so it's out:

[image]

However, that's precisely the kind of responsiveness I need. Can someone help me find a workaround that incorporates `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and is fully responsive? Or is that not possible?

Ideally, I don't want to have to change my CSS too much - it's working as expected in most cases, and it doesn't employ CSS3 (which I need to avoid to cater to older devices - another one of my requirements). I'd prefer well-supported CSS properties as per caniuse.com.

---

**Update:** Adding `width:100%` and `max-width:400px;` to `.canvas` almost solves the problem, except the polaroid canvas starts overflowing the containing div *even though it does get smaller with res*. Behold:

[image]

That blue strip in the background is the containing div (and it's bigger than that, but cropped in the image).

Comment: i cannot reproduce the bug, can u please share a jsfiddle or post all the code , icant see that you are using a border right here

Comment: @GmaSa: https://jsfiddle.net/yes13cr6/ does this work?

Comment: same it's work normal , which browser you are using ??? - also u can just use `border: 5px solid lightblue;` so he follow and get radius automatic with the container . no need to setup a several containers one inside another. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yes13cr6/3/) <--- mess with `width:30%` to see the differents

Comment: @SUB-HDR: that has its own issues. See the update I did at the end of the question. We are close, but thats not the solution for me.

Comment: what u mean by containing div ? which one ?

Comment: where is the blue containing in your HTML code ?? add that containing div in your (jsfiddle) press update, copy the link and post it and we can see and test the problem ourselves. cause your code show us only the white container

Comment: @SUB-HDR: I did all that: https://jsfiddle.net/yes13cr6/8/ Try resizing the resolution, the polaroid overflows the blue container if you look closely.

Comment: here is your solution : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838006/7465452) -----

Answer (score 3, accepted):

♦ in your (`.canvas`) Add this :

```
-webkit-box-sizing : border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
        box-sizing : border-box;
```

✘ and from your html its better if you *remove* this :

```
<div class="card" style="margin-top:1.3em;background-color:#BDEBFE;text-align:right;">
```

✔ and replace it with this ***iD*** :

```
<div id="card">
```

then in your css use :

```
#card {
   margin-top:1.3em;
   padding:6px;
   background-color:#BDEBFE;
   text-align:right;
   max-width:400px;
   }

.canvas{     
-webkit-box-sizing : border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
        box-sizing : border-box;

  background-color:white;
  padding:10px 10px 30px 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:6px;
  max-width:400px;
  width:100%;
}
```

> Example : [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/yes13cr6/12/)

---

[image: Browsers support for box-sizing]

> **Note** : why we used ID in the first container instead of class ?
>   in your specific settings and because your using 2 containers one inside another and both uses 'class', 
>  somehow it
>   seems to not allow that first container to show the background even when using `padding` ,thats why we use ID in the First Container instead , and thats why i told
>   you before to use ***border*** in your `.canvas` better and get ride of that `card` div container . but if u want it with 2 containers then u most use an ID first .

Comment: btw quick question: why is it better to use `id` instead of a `class` in this case?

Comment: @HassanBaig > when there is 2 containers one inside another and both uses `class`, 
somehow it seems to not allow that ***first*** container to show the background even when using `padding`,thats why we use ID in the First Container instead , **and thats why i told you before to use border in your .canvas better** and get ride of that card div container ...  **but** if u want it with 2 containers then u most use an ID first .

Comment: Yep, using `box-sizing : border-box;` solves my problem. Great answer, I'll mark this correct. But before I do, I have a quick question: applying `box-sizing : border-box;` causes all my images to slightly **decrease** their width. That's probably because the 400px max-width now contains border elements too. What could be a work-around to still impose the original widths on the image while using `box-sizing : border-box;`? Or is that not possible?

Comment: @HassanBaig > didn't understand exactly what you trying to reach but `box-sizing` have nothing to do with the image width, you have to change the content settings till you find what u want, and based on what i understand a lil bit from you . maybe something like: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yes13cr6/14/) ,the `max-width` in your `#card{}` + `.canvas{}` you can remove them ,and add to your image class `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;` also remove: `width:100%;` from your `.image{}` class to allow the image to increase or decrease Depending on original size + the min size of the container.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to show long words without breaking them. At some point there will be no more room, so the only other way to show long words without breaking them is to use a smaller font on smaller screens.
What you can do is use `hyphens` to allow hyphenation. Just add `hyphens: auto` to your `.caption`

More info on hyphens: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

About that container overflow: I added `word-break: break-word` to your `.caption` class, which made the polaroid scale down but break the long words - better the long words than all words i guess ;) See everything in the codepen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEvzwM

Comment: Well, to be exact, my problem is how the image becomes unresponsive to changes in screen size for long strings (even if one uses `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and `hyphens: auto`): https://jsfiddle.net/yes13cr6/

Comment: The image becomes unresponsive due to the long text beneath it - it has no need to get smaller because the text is still long and defines the width of the conainer. Breaking the text using hyphens or `word-break: break-word` changes that, so the image has to resize.

Comment: No what I meant was `hyphens:auto` isn't the solution. If you see the fiddle I included, adding hyphens to it doesn't make the included image responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query and something like this for small screens:

```
text-align: justify;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

I do not see Your HTML but overflow-wrap only for `.caption` shouldn't have impact on image resize if image is in different div ... ok I see it...

just add this two rules not for `.canvas` but for `.caption-canvas` or even for `.caption-canvas .canvas{ }`

Ps. You have two `.canvas` classes, one for container and one for it child.